# Is there a way to replace TextView text with a String in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

In essence, I am trying to replace the text that a TextView element contains with a string obtained from scanning a QR code, to test if the scanner actually works

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the text with the setText function

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

and here's a really nice article if that doesn't work as expected (debugging you may find that the TextView has the text you want, but is not displayed on the screen yet):

https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-app-text-not-updating